# Separating data from views with mustache.js in node

Tags: node.js, mustache

I would like to separate the template from the data using mustache.js in node... It is not obvious using fs.readFile if this is possible.  Any Thoughts?

I'm using data.js as the array model and helloworld.html as the template

```
var mustache = require('mustache');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('request recieved at ' + (new Date()).getTime());
  fs.readFile('./data.js', encoding='utf8',function(err, data) {
     model2 = data;
     console.log(model2);  //logs the data.js as expected
  });
  fs.readFile('./helloworld.html', function(err, template) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(mustache.to_html(template.toString(),model2));  //model2 is not being passed in
  });
}).listen(8081);
```

Comment: I would advice you to have a look at http://jade-lang.com. This can be used with http://expressjs.com. This way you can get really clean code. I think both these product are really good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [jinjs](http://code.ravelsoft.com/node-jinjs). It is a port of the Jinja, a very good Python templating system. You can install it with npm like this :

```
npm install jinjs
```

in template.tpl :

```
I say : "{{ sentence }}"
```

in your template.js :

```
jinjs = require('jinjs');
jinjs.registerExtension('.tpl');
tpl = require('./template');
str = tpl.render ({sentence : 'Hello, World!'});
console.log(str);
```

The output will be :

```
I say : "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: thanks guys - I will look at jinjs.  I did modify my code to use more of the jade capability.  It really came down to altering the data model to make it more compatible, and where it isn't to adjust the data coming in with javascript.